# What is fix equivalent function in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using Mvc framework and i want to migrate vb code to c#. Right now i want to use** FIX ** function equivalent in c#

Example:- **Vb Code**

```
result.ReducedDegrees= Fix(dblReducedAngle)    
result.ReducedMinutes = Fix((dblReducedAngle - Fix(dblReducedAngle)) * 60)
```

I want to get result in c#

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/235709-c-equivalent-question). You're looking for `Math.Floor` / `Math.Ceiling`.

Comment: Math.Ceiling is working for me ,Thanks  @diiN_

Comment: Math.Ceiling only works for positive numbers, mind. Use Math.Truncate to make it work for both positive and negative numbers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Fix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh29swte(v=vs.90).aspx) function removes the fractional part of a numeric expression. Closely the same functionality as Int, except the Fix method has a special clause at the bottom:

> If Number is negative, Fix returns the first negative integer greater than or equal to Number.

In C#, there is the [Math.Truncate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2eabd70(v=vs.110).aspx) method which you can use. It has the same properties as VB's Fix method.